# Create a directory if it doesn't exist when symlinking a file into that directory

Tags: symlink

Assume I want to symlink like in the following command:

```bsh
ln -s /home/user/dots/cmus/cmus.theme /home/user/cmus/cmus.theme
```

But for the above command to work, I need to make sure that the directory `/home/user/cmus` is already existing. Otherwise, there will be error. Is there a way to work around this like `mkdir -p`?

In order to make my problem clear, I'll put down my use case. I want to create a shell script which will symlink my dotfiles in appropriate locations. Until now, I have the following:

```bsh
DIR=$HOME/projects/dotFiles

DOTFILES=(
    "bin"
    ".bashrc"
    ".bash_profile"
    ".gitconfig"
    ".profile"
    ".tmux.conf"
    ".xinitrc"
    ".config/cmus/cmus.theme"
    ".config/compton.conf"
    ".config/dunst"
    ".config/feh"
    ".config/mpv"
    ".config/nvim"
    ".config/ranger"
    ".local/share/fonts"
)

for dotfile in "${DOTFILES[@]}";do
    rm -rf "${HOME}/${dotfile}"
    ln -sf "${DIR}/${dotfile}" "${HOME}/${dotfile}"
done
```

But, I have no idea how I can work around the problem I specified without explicitly creating the directory beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re using GNU `cp`, you can use [its `-s` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html#index-symbolic-links_002c-copying-with):

```
cd "${HOME}"
cp -rs "${DIR}/.*" "${DIR}/*" .
```

This will create the appropriate directory hierarchies and symlink files instead of copying them.